# Render 4K Desktop onto a 2K screen

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview

Sorry for the bad title, It's really hard to find an appropriate title.

Basically since I've gotten a 2K Desktop anytime I use my laptop (Which is 1080p) now I will use RDP with Smart Scaling and a resolution of 2K so I have a matching resolution on my laptop (I am aware that it is no longer sharp since the laptop is not really 1440p)

I wanted to try a resolution of 4K on my 2K monitor to see if I could properly utilize the space available. Unfortunately you can't RDP into the same machine. I am wondering if it is possible to effectively achieve the same thing as above on the same computer. So my Windows will render a 4K desktop onto my 2K monitor.

To be clear, I'm not expecting my monitor to magically gain pixels. I want more desktop space at the sacrifice of clarity.

Thanks!

Comment: I've been looking for years for something like this, but I was unable to find any solution. Some programs that offer a virtual desktop space, simply create scrollbars but doesn't actually zoom out. Virtual Machines would be an option, but they often are so smart that they'll match your desktop space or offer that resolution as a max, not allowing you to go bigger. I haven't posted this as an aswer in the hopes someone actually does know a solution.

Comment: @LPChip I was thinking of using a dumb terminal to remote desktop into my main machine. But I'd rather just have this possible on the one machine.
Virtual Machines should work fine if you remote desktop into them using mstsc.exe. The only thing you need to be aware of is that you need to save your RDP settings and manually edit them. Adding in Smart Sizing and the resolution you desire. I just don't really have the space for a VM like that.

Comment: oh, thats interesting. Might be something I can try for my work laptop as it has only 1366x768 resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have any decently modern graphics chip, you are very likely to be able to activate features such as Nvidia's DSR or AMD's VSR technologies.

They function in the same way, by rendering the entire screen or even selected applications at a different resolution than the native one and then downsampling it using an antialiasing filter. Text and icons can get quite unreadable and small but it works fine.

For Nvidia cards, you first have to select which scaling factor/s you want for DSR in the control panel under "Manage 3d settings" (say, 1.5x, 2x, 4x) and then those new resolutions will be available to use under "screen resolution" options. Tweak the "DSR - Smoothness" option to change filter size.
On AMD Catalyst it should be equally easy to activate.

In DSR/VSR mode, everytime you try to do a screenshot or do video capturing off a videogame you are actually saving the full 4k picture, not the downscaled one.

You probably want to check your mouse sensitivity afterwards. Just saying.